# Install Java 10 using Oracle JDK

Tags: ubuntu, java, ppa, jdk

I have updated my system, then added a third-party PPA to Ubuntu with the following command.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
```

But this is what I got:

```
$ sudo apt install oracle-java10-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package oracle-java10-installer is not available, but is referred to by another
package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'oracle-java10-installer' has no installation candidate
```

Can you guys help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Oracle 10 was removed from the PPA. Upgrade to Oracle Java 11 or 12 or the  [OpenJDK 11](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/openjdk-11-jdk) Ubuntu package.

https://launchpad.net/~linuxuprising/+archive/ubuntu/java

> About Oracle Java 10: This version reached the end of public updates, therefore it's no longer available for download. The Oracle Java 10 packages in this PPA no longer worked due to this, so I have removed them. Switch to Oracle Java 11 or OpenJDK 11 instead, which is long term support.

Instruction links copied from above link:

- [New Oracle Java 11 Installer For Ubuntu Or Linux Mint (Using Local Oracle Java .tar.gz)](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/06/new-oracle-java-11-installer-for-ubuntu.html)
- [How To Install Oracle Java 12 (JDK 12) In Ubuntu, Linux Mint Or Debian (Using PPA)](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-12-jdk-12-in.html)